# SwiftMailer ReturnPath

Tags: php, yii2, email

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с письмами которые возвращаются, если не были доставлены по какой-то причине.

Их нужно переадресовать на другой емейл.
Но заголовок `return-path` не работает.

Я устанавливаю свой `return-path`, но, после отправки, приходит письмо не на тот ящик который указан, а на тот, с которого отправляли, при чем в письме затирается мой установленный емейл.

Пример моего кода:

```
    $body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
    $body .= '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
    $body .= '<head>';
    $body .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="' . Yii::$app->charset . '" />';
    $body .= '<title></title>';
    $body .= '</head>';
    $body .= '<body>';
    $body .= 'Test Message';
    $body .= '</body>';
    $body .= '</html>';



    Yii::$app->mailer->useTransport('system')->compose()
        ->setFrom(['example@some.com' => 'example.com'])
        ->setReturnPath('bounced@some.com')
        ->addHeader('Reply-To', 'bounced@some.com')
        ->setTo('example2@some.com')
        ->setSubject('TEST MESSAGE')
        ->setHtmlBody($body)
        ->send();
```

Для отправки почты использую `swiftmailer`.

Гуглил я уже достаточно долго, установка каких-либо других заголовков к положительному результату не привела.

Может у вас есть какие либо варианты?

Хидеры, которые приходят в ответ:

```
Return-path: <example@some.com>
Envelope-to: example2@some.com
Delivery-date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 17:42:28 +0300
Received: from some.com ([159.203.33.129])
    by site.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <example@some.com>)
    id 1buhDH-0002DI-S0
    for example2@some.com; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 17:42:27 +0300
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=site.com; s=dkim;
    h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:To:From:Subject:Date:Message-ID; bh=TJEj83H/pPguf4pMS+4FcdmBzKkRiY+DeLg2oWD2/iQ=;
    b=kA3lrgCRo3Wqr6ky6JVhytV6m/Qx1L3NXFybgPWxyBE5bEqqFGWgOEJQd5O5sppbDnfWB780Hz0FKA8OiiT3IrbzvohHzjRf5SD/IYFz6IaGaN9jwVTojo5jFfBv8t6lv9KprH6MFQEqKJ8bqKNGp3HYIWlr6DXQAEAAl6CogqY=;
Received: from [178.74.217.102] (helo=[127.0.0.1])
    by site.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.84_2)
    (envelope-from <example@some.com>)
    id 1buhDG-0001i4-Su
    for example2@some.com; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 10:42:27 -0400
Message-ID: <34cb7242e992226ad1d1f74b821c325f@swift.generated>
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 10:42:25 -0400
Subject: TEST MESSAGE
From: "Example.com" <example@some.com>
To: example2@some.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

**UDP.**
Для отсылки емейлов используется `mailjet`.

Comment: > Я устанавливаю свой return-path, но после отправки, приходит письмо не на тот ящик который указан , а на тот с которого отправляли , при чем в письме затирается мой установленный емейл.

Это стандартное поведение.
Bounce задается командой SMTP "MAIL FROM".
Какой транспорт вы используете? Sendmail и SMTP должны брать это значение из setReturnPath.

Comment: @VladislavRoss, использую SMTP.
ну так return-path вроде как должен браться оттуда, но я наблюдаю совсем другую картину.
Вы же видите что в настройках я всё таки прописываю этот путь.

Comment: Раз уж такая нетривиальная проблема, то я бы залез в код класса SMTP-траспорта и залогировал, что он пишет в порт. Если он пишет MAIL FROM bounced@some.com, то все правильно, и это уже сервер самовольно шлет баунс не туда.

Comment: @VladislavRoss, попробую залогировать это дело

Comment: расскажите, что вы в итоге выяснили

Comment: Не ваш случай? http://serverfault.com/questions/113726/linux-exim-set-return-path-header-automaticly-using-from-header

Comment: @DmitryKozlov к сожалению нет, менять что то в конфиге нет возможности, только программный метод, если такой возможен

Comment: Тогда надо выяснить у админа. Беглый поиск показывает, что этот  заголовок может быть отключен в конфигах эксима или заменяться в правилах фильтрации

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, собственно я к такому же выводу пришел, так как все что я смог нагуглить , тупо не сработало .....

Answer (score 1):

А вы пробовали указать `setSender()` вместо `setReturnPath`?

Подобные проблемы возникали и у этих людей:

https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/384

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762802/phpmailer-bounced-mails-not-getting-bounced-right/26765956#26765956

Comment: указывал этот хидер, но всё так же